# How to test chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a good way to do this? I'm writing an extension that interacts with a website as a content script and saves data using localstorage. Are there any tools, frameworks, etc. that I can use to test this behavior? I realize there are some generic tools for testing javascript, but are those sufficiently power to test an extension? Unit testing is most important, but I'm also interested in other types of testing (such as integration testing).

Comment: I've just written a canonical answer which addresses unit testing and integration testing for browser extensions across *all* browsers, not just Chrome. See [the answer to "Testing browser extensions"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17370531/938089).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Yes, the existing frameworks are pretty useful..

In the recent past, I have placed all my tests on a "test" page that was embedded in to the application but not reachable unless physically typed.

For instance, I would have all the tests in a page accessible under `chrome-extension://asdasdasdasdad/unittests.html`

The tests would have access to `localStorage` etc.  For accessing content scripts, in theory you could test that through embedded IFRAMEs in your test page, however these are more integration level testing, unit tests would require you to abstract that away from real pages so that you don't depend on them, likewise with access to localStorage.

If you want to test pages directly, you can orchestrate your extension to open new tabs (chrome.tab.create({"url" : "someurl"}).  For each of the new tabs your content script should run and you can use your testing framework to check that your code has done what it should do.

As for frameworks, [JsUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) or the more recent [Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine) should work fine.

Comment: You're right, testing real pages doesn't fall under unit testing. I should have made my question more broad. But it's still something I'd like to test, especially since the website html structure could change at any time. I've modified the question.

Comment: I would test through IFrames in your unit test page still.  The content scripts should still fire (if you enable the scripts to run in the iFrame)

Comment: The proxy sample extension has some tests which just mock out the bits and pieces of the Chrome APIs that were necessary: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#chrome.proxy
 .. Also our colleague Boris  used QUnit for testing his "model" layer: https://github.com/borismus/Question-Monitor-for-Stack-Exchange/tree/master/tests

Answer (score 71):

Working on several chrome extensions I came up with [`sinon-chrome`](https://github.com/vitalets/sinon-chrome) project that allows to run unit-tests using `mocha`, `nodejs` and `phantomjs`.

Basically, it creates sinon mocks of all `chrome.*` API where you can put any predefined json responses.

Next, you load your scripts using node's `vm.runInNewContext` for background page and `phantomjs` for render popup / options page.

And finally, you assert that chrome api was called with needed arguments.

**Let's take an example:**
Assume we have simple chrome extension that displays number of opened tabs in button badge.

*background page:*

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(tabs.length)});
});
```

To test it we need:

1. mock `chrome.tabs.query` to return predefined response, e.g. two tabs.
2. inject our mocked `chrome.*` api into some environment
3. run our extension code in this environment
4. assert that button badge equals to '2'

The code snippet is following:

```
const vm = require('vm');
const fs = require('fs');
const chrome = require('sinon-chrome');

// 1. mock `chrome.tabs.query` to return predefined response 
chrome.tabs.query.yields([
  {id: 1, title: 'Tab 1'}, 
  {id: 2, title: 'Tab 2'}
]);

// 2. inject our mocked chrome.* api into some environment
const context = {
  chrome: chrome
};

// 3. run our extension code in this environment
const code = fs.readFileSync('src/background.js');
vm.runInNewContext(code, context);

// 4. assert that button badge equals to '2'
sinon.assert.calledOnce(chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText);
sinon.assert.calledWithMatch(chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText, {
  text: "2"
});
```

Now we can wrap it into mocha's `describe..it` functions and run from terminal:

```
$ mocha

background page
  ✓ should display opened tabs count in button badge

1 passing (98ms)
```

You can find full example [here](https://github.com/acvetkov/sinon-chrome/tree/76cbfc1c64355a94eb29e2de2119449956d6c2e5/example).

Additionally, sinon-chrome allows to trigger any chrome event with predefined response, e.g.

```
chrome.tab.onCreated.trigger({url: 'http://google.com'});
```

Comment: The link for the example seems to be dead - could you please update it?

Comment: Updated link to example. Also sinon-chrome is now moved to https://github.com/acvetkov and there will be new examples soon

Comment: Note: Project appears to be stale: The last commit was on *Nov 26, 2019*, issues remain unanswered.

Answer (score 5):

While `sinon.js` seems to work great, you can also just use plain Jasmine and mock the Chrome callbacks you need. Example:

[Mock](https://github.com/serv-inc/JSGuardian/blob/master/test/src/mockExt.js)

```
chrome = {
  runtime: {
    onMessage : {
      addListener : function() {}
    }
  }
}
```

[Test](https://github.com/serv-inc/JSGuardian/blob/master/test/spec/LibSpec.js)

```
describe("JSGuardian", function() {

  describe("BlockCache", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      this.blockCache = new BlockCache();
    });

    it("should recognize added urls", function() {
      this.blockCache.add("http://some.url");
      expect(this.blockCache.allow("http://some.url")).toBe(false);
    });
} // ... etc
```

Just modify the default [`SpecRunner.html`](https://github.com/serv-inc/JSGuardian/blob/master/test/SpecRunner.html) to run your code.

Answer (score 3):

About already existing tool in Chrome:

1. In the chrome developer tool, there is section for Resources For local storage.

   Developer Tools > Resources > Local Storage

   See the changes of localstorage there.
2. You can use console.profile to test performance and watch run time call stack.
3. for fileSystem You can use this URL to check your file is upload-ed or not: 
   filesystem:chrome-extension:///temporary/

If you are use content script and local-storage together without background page/script and without message passing, local-storage will be accessible from that site only. 
So, to test those pages, you have to inject your test script in those tabs.

Comment: Did not work for me, but it did get me further along in my javascript. +1 for that.

Comment: For fileSystem You can use: 

filesystem:chrome-extension://<yourextension-id>/temporary/

Answer (score 2):

I found that I can use **Selenium web driver** for starting fresh browser instance with preinstalled extension and [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) for clicks - because Selenium cannot drive "view" of the extension. After clicks you can make screenshots and compare them with 'expected' ones, expecting 95% of similarity (because on different browsers it is acceptable markup movements to a few pixels).

Answer (score 2):

To test End-to-End you can use `puppeteer`.
Here is snippet I wrote for my extension to check loaded extension `title` and to verify if extension was enabled in incognito mode.

```js
const path = require("path");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const assert = require("assert");
const Constants = require("../contants");
const Utils = require("./util");

const extensionID = Constants.EXTENSION_ID;
const extensionPath = path.join(__dirname, "../dist");
const extensionOptionHtml = "option.html";
const extPage = `chrome-extension://${extensionID}/${extensionOptionHtml}`;
let extensionPage = null;
let browser = null;

async function boot() {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    // slowMo: 250,
    headless: false, // extension are allowed only in head-full mode
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${extensionPath}`,
      `--load-extension=${extensionPath}`,
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
    ]
  });

  extensionPage = await browser.newPage();
  await extensionPage.goto(extPage);
}

describe("Extension UI Testing", function() {
  this.timeout(20000); // default is 2 seconds and that may not be enough to boot browsers and pages.
  before(async function() {
    await boot();
  });

  describe("option page home", async function() {
    it("check title", async function() {
      const h1 = "Allow extension in Incognito Mode";
      const extH1 = await extensionPage.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelector("h1").textContent.trim()
      );
      assert.equal(extH1, h1);
    });
    it("show option ui after enabling extension in incognito", async () => {
      await extensionPage.goto(`chrome://extensions/?id=${extensionID}`);
      extensionPage.evaluate(() =>
        document
          .querySelector("body > extensions-manager")
          .shadowRoot.querySelector("#viewManager > extensions-detail-view")
          .shadowRoot.querySelector("#allow-incognito")
          .shadowRoot.querySelector("#crToggle")
          .click()
      );
      await Utils.sleep(2000);
      await extensionPage.goto(
        `chrome-extension://${extensionID}/${extensionOptionHtml}`
      );
      const h3 = "Mark Incognito";
      const headingID = `#${Constants.OPTION_SCRIPT_HOST_ID} > div > div > header > div > h6`;
      await extensionPage.waitFor(headingID);
      console.log({ headingID });
      const extH3 = await extensionPage.evaluate(headingID => {
        return document.querySelector(headingID).textContent.trim();
      }, headingID);
      console.log({ extH3 });
      assert.equal(extH3, h3);
    });
  });

  after(async function() {
    await browser.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To confirm a couple previous answers, Jasmine seems to work well with Chrome extensions. I'm using version 3.4.0.

You can use [Jasmine spies](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html) to easily create test doubles for the various APIs. No need to build your own from scratch. For example:

```
describe("Test suite", function() {

  it("Test case", function() {

    // Set up spies and fake data.
    spyOn(chrome.browserAction, "setPopup");
    spyOn(chrome.identity, "removeCachedAuthToken");
    fakeToken = "faketoken-faketoken-faketoken";
    fakeWindow = jasmine.createSpyObj("window", ["close"]);

    // Call the function under test.
    logout(fakeWindow, fakeToken);

    // Perform assertions.
    expect(chrome.browserAction.setPopup).toHaveBeenCalledWith({popup: ""});
    expect(chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken).toHaveBeenCalledWith({token: fakeToken});
    expect(fakeWindow.close.calls.count()).toEqual(1);

  });

});
```

Some more details, if it helps:

As mentioned in another answer, I created an HTML page as part of my browser extension that runs my tests. The HTML page includes the Jasmine library, plus my extension's JavaScript code, plus my test suite. The tests are run automatically and the results are formatted for you. No need to build a test runner or a results formatter. Just follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine#installation), and use the HTML documented there to create your test runner page, and include your test suite in the page as well.

I don't think you can fetch the Jasmine framework dynamically from another host, so I just included the Jasmine release in my extension. I will omit it and also my test cases when I build my extension for production, of course.

I haven't looked at how to execute my tests at the command line. That would be handy for automated deployment tools.