# Testing browser extensions

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, bdd, browser-extension

I'm going to write bunch of browser extensions (the same functionality for each popular browser). I hope, that some of the code will be shared, but I'm not sure about this yet. For sure some of extensions will use native API. I have not much experience with TDD/BDD, and I thought it's good time to start folowing these ideas from this project.

The problem is, I have no idea how to handle it. Should I write different tests for each browser? How far should I go with these tests? These extensions will be quite simple - some data in a local storage, refreshing a page and listening through web sockets.

And my observation about why is it hard for me - because there is a lot of behaviour, and not so much models, which are also dependent on a platform.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I practise two different ways of testing my browser extensions:

- Unit tests
- Integration test

## Introduction

I will use the cross-browser [YouTube Lyrics by Rob W](https://robwu.nl/youtubelyrics/) extension as an example throughout this answer. The core of this extension is written in JavaScript and organized with AMD modules. A build script generates the extension files for each browser. With [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/), I streamline the inclusion of browser-specific modules, such as the one for cross-origin HTTP requests and persistent storage (for preferences), and a module with tons of polyfills for IE.

The extension inserts a panel with lyrics for the currently played song on YouTube, Grooveshark and Spotify. I have no control over these third-party sites, so I need an automated way to verify that the extension still works well.

#### Workflow

During development:

1. Implement / edit feature, and write a unit test if the feature is not trivial.
2. Run all *unit tests* to see if anything broke. If anything is wrong, go back to 1.
3. Commit to git.

Before release:

1. Run all *unit tests* to verify that the individual modules is still working.
2. Run all *integration tests* to verify that the extension as whole is still working.
3. Bump versions, build extensions.
4. Upload update to the official extension galleries and my website (Safari and IE extensions have to be hosted by yourself) and commit to git.

## Unit testing

I use [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) + [expect.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/expect.js/) to write tests. I don't test every method for each module, just the ones that matter. For instance:

- The DOM parsing method. Most DOM parsing methods in the wild (including jQuery) are flawed: Any external resources are loaded and JavaScript is executed.
  I verify that the DOM parsing method correctly parses DOM without negative side effects.
- The preference module: I verify that data can be saved and returned.
- My extension fetches lyrics from external sources. These sources are defined in separate modules. These definitions are recognized and used by the `InfoProvider` module, which takes a query, (black box), and outputs the search results.

  - First I test whether the `InfoProvider` module functions correctly.
  - Then, for each of the 17 sources, I pass a pre-defined query to the source (with `InfoProvider`) and verify that the results are expected:

    - The query succeeds
    - The returned song title matches (by [applying](http://jsperf.com/dice-s-similarity-coefficient-hash-vs-array) a word similarity algorithm)
    - The length of the returned lyrics fall inside the expected range.
- Whether the UI is not obviously broken, e.g. by clicking on the Close button.

These tests can be run directly from a local server, or within a browser extension. The advantage of the local server is that you can edit the test and refresh the browser to see the results. If all of these tests pass, I run the tests from the browser extension.
By passing an extra parameter `debug` to my build script, the unit tests are bundled with my extension.

Running the tests within a web page is not sufficient, because the extension's environment may differ from the normal page. For instance, in an Opera 12 extension, there's no global `location` object.

Remark: I don't include the tests in the release build. Most users don't take the efforts to report and investigate bugs, they will just give a low rating and say something like "Doesn't work". Make sure that your extension functions without obvious bugs before shipping it.

#### Summary

- View modules as black boxes. You don't care what's inside, as long as the output matches is expected or a given input.
- Start with testing the critical parts of your extension.
- Make sure that the tests can be build and run easily, possibly in a non-extension environment.
- Don't forget to run the tests within the extension's execution context, to ensure that there's no constraint or unexpected condition inside the extension's context which break your code.

## Integration testing

I use Selenium 2 to test whether my extension still works on YouTube, Grooveshark (3x) and Spotify.

Initially, I just used the [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp) to record tests and see if it worked. That went well, until I needed more flexibility: I wanted to conditionally run a test depending on whether the test account was logged in or not. That's not possible with the default Selenium IDE (it's said to be possible with the [FlowControl plugin](https://github.com/davehunt/selenium-ide-flowcontrol) - I haven't tried).

The Selenium IDE offers an option to export the existing tests in other formats, including JUnit 4 tests (Java). Unfortunately, this result wasn't satisfying. Many commands were not recognized.

So, I abandoned the Selenium IDE, and switched to Selenium.
Note that when you search for "Selenium", you will find information about Selenium RC (Selenium 1) and Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2). The first is the old and deprecated, the latter (Selenium WebDriver) should be used for new projects.

Once you discovered how the documentation works, it's quite easy to use.
I prefer the documentation at the project page, because it's generally concise (the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/w/list)) and complete (the [Java docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html)).

If you want to get started quickly, read the [Getting Started wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted). If you've got spare time, look through the [documentation at SeleniumHQ](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/), in particular the [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) and [WebDriver: Advanced Usage](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).
[Selenium Grid](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) is also worth reading. This feature allows you to distribute tests across different (virtual) machines. Great if you want to test your extension in IE8, 9 and 10, *simultaneously* (to run multiple versions of Internet Explorer, you need virtualization).

Automating tests is nice. What's more nice? Automating installation of extensions!
The [ChromeDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) and [FirefoxDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) support the installation of extensions, as seen in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17117849/938089).

For the [SafariDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver), I've written two classes to install a custom Safari extension. I've published it and sent in a PR to Selenium, so it might be available to everyone in the future: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/87

The [OperaDriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operadriver) does not support installation of custom extensions (technically, it should be possible though).
Note that with the advent of [Chromium-powered Opera](http://business.opera.com/press/releases/desktop/2013-05-28), the old OperaDriver doesn't work any more.

There's an [Internet Explorer Driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver), and this one does definitely not allow one to install a custom extension. Internet Explorer doesn't have built-in support for extensions. Extensions are installed through MSI or EXE installers, which are not even integrated in Internet Explorer. So, in order to automatically install your extension in IE, you need to be able to silently run an installer which installs your IE plugin. I haven't tried this *yet*.

Comment: It is marvelous! Thank you for the excellent, extremely detailed answer, definitely can be considered as canonical answer.

Comment: @MaksimMorozov I have implemented automated installation of Opera extensions, so that brings the number of automated extension installs to 4: 2 in the official Selenium repositories, and 2 on https://github.com/Rob--W/. Installation instructions are written at the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17117849/938089).

Comment: What build system do you use? Also, has anything better emerged in the 5 years since you wrote this?

Comment: Great answer, aged quite well, but.. What did "most DOM parsers including jQuery are flawed" mean, really?

Answer (score 4):

Testing browser extensions posed some difficulty for me as well, but I've settled on  implementing tests in a few different areas that I can invoke simultaneously from browsers driven by Selenium.

The steps I use are:

First, I write test code integrated into the extension code that can be activated by simply going to a specific URL.  When the extension sees that URL, it begins running the tests.

Then, in the page that activates the testing in the extension I execute server-side tests to be sure the API performs, and record and log issues there.  I record the methods invoked, the time they took, and any errors.  So I can see the method the extension invoked, the web performance, the business logic performance, and the database performance.

Lastly, I automatically invoke browsers to point at that specific URL and record their performance along with other test information, errors, etc on any given client system using Selenium:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

This way I can break down the tests in terms of browser, extension, server, application, and database and link them all together according to specific test sets.  It takes a bit of work to put it all together, but once its done you can have a very nice extension testing framework.

Typically for cross-browser extension development in order to maintain a single code-base I use crossrider, but you can do this with any framework or with native extensions as you wish, Selenium won't care, it is just driving the extension to a particular page and allowing you to interact and perform tests.

One nice thing about this approach is you can use it for live users as well.  If you are providing support for your extension, have a user go to your test url and immediately you will see the extension and server-side performance.  You won't get the Selenium tests of course, but you will capture a lot of issues this way - very useful when you are coding against a variety of browsers and browser versions.

Comment: Is it possible to work with Selenium in Chrome extension testing ?