# Control browser plugins with Selenium

Tags: selenium

Is it possible to control plugins like FlashGot for FF with Selenium? If yes how? The only related stuff I've found regarding plugins and Selenium is [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005833/browser-plugin-testing-with-selenium) question which only mention (un)installation of plugin using Selenium.

Comment: you can use firefox profile to launch browser with the desired pluging.

Comment: @pArAs I am asking if it is possible to control particular plugin functionality not if it possible to launch FF with particular plugin. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ohh ok .. my bad! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** possible to test Addons with Selenium, since they live outside browser DOM.

However you can use [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class to simulate mouse actions done by user. Another option would be to use Sikuli.

Example of Robot class usage is given in this [blog post](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke)