# Is there a way to automate the testing of chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webdriver, gruntjs, tdd

I'm writing an extension for Google's Chrome browser and, in good TDD fashion, I'd like to start writing some BDD-like end-to-end integration tests before I start.

However, I'm finding documentation on how to automate Chrome extension is sparse especially if you're using JavaScript/Grunt.

The main problem being: how do I automatically install a Chrome extension in your Webdriver run?

As far as I can see the only way to do this is in Java:

http://releasematic.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/automation-testing-chrome-extensions/

No similar API exists for Javascript! Is this correct? Is anyone else automating the testing of their chrome extensions?

Comment: A couple of duplicate candidates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869827/how-to-test-chrome-extensions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798528/testing-browser-extensions