# How to mock chrome.cookies.getAll using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, jasmine, stub

I have the following code in `background.js`

```
var allCookies = [];
function getAllCookies() {
   chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function(cookies) {
    for (var i in cookies) {
      allCookies.push(cookies[i])
     }
    }
   });
}
```

Now in `specs.js`, I have written the following code to test the `getAllCookies` method -

```
describe('getAllCookies', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      chrome = {
        cookies: {
            getAll : function() { 
                return [
                    'cookie1',
                    'cookie2'
                ]
            }
        }
      };
      spyOn(chrome.cookies,'getAll');
    });
    it('should updated global variable allCookies', function() {
      getAllCookies();
      expect(allCookies).toEqual(['cookie1','cookie2'])
    })
  })
```

But the test is failing as `allCookies = []` but it should be equal to `['cookie1','cookie2']`

**Can someone please help me to mock such chrome APIs (say `chrome.cookies.getAll`) which takes callback function as argument?**

Comment: Have you had a look at sinon-chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869827/how-to-test-chrome-extensions and https://github.com/acvetkov/sinon-chrome?